# XML failure in XSD Schemas for MSML (RFC 5707)

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to find somewhere valid xml schemas for [Media Server Markup Language (MSML) - RFC 5707](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5707). I need to write a parser but I only find these spec doc. I copy & paste them into .xsd files. But it seems that their is an error. I used JAXB to create from theses schemas classes but there occurs this error:
(I translated the error message into english)

> [ERROR] Elementtyp "xs:complexType" need a appropriate Endtag
> "</xs:com plexType>".   Row 332 von
> file:/E:/Downloads/jaxb-ri-2.2.6/bin/msml-dialog-base-datatypes.xsd

I checked the file with eclipse, and the problem is in this element definition:

```
<xs:element name="dtmfgen" substitutionGroup="primitive">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:extension base="primitiveType">
     <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="dtmfgenexit">
       <xs:complexType>
        <xs:group ref="sendType"/>
       </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
     </xs:choice>
     <xs:attribute name="level" use="optional" default="-6">
      <xs:simpleType>
       <xs:restriction base="xs:nonPositiveInteger">
        <xs:maxInclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:minInclusive value="-96"/>
       </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
     </xs:attribute>
     <xs:attribute name="digits" type="dtmfDigits.datatype"
                   use="required"/>
     <xs:attribute name="dur" type="posDuration.datatype" use="optional"
                   default="100ms"/>
     <xs:attribute name="interval" type="posDuration.datatype"
                   use="optional" default="100ms"/>
    </xs:extension>
   </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

I can't find a solution to fix it so maybe someone of you can help me. Or give me a link to valid xsd package for MSML. Or even better someone has a parser for me.?

Thanks
G.

Answer (score 0):

You have been the victim of a copy/paste error which has rendered your copy of the declaration ill formed:  somewhere along the way, the start-tag for `xs:complexContent` (which occurs as a child of `xs:complexType` and as the parent of `xs:extension`) was dropped.

I infer that it was was a copy/paste error because the XSD schema document in RFC 2707 does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The posted error message has something to do with how cut and paste worked for you, most likely.

Still, even if you fix that, you're still going to have two issues (known about... at least to those who tried it before...):

- use of an invalid pattern (unescaped -)
- a duplicate definition for the **msml** element (once in msml-core and once in msml.xsd).

[This archive](http://www.paschidev.com/schemas/MSML.zip) contains all the files you need; they are valid which means all the necessary fixes have been applied already.

Comment: Link is still dead! Is there an other source available?

Comment: Could u please upload it somewhere else or send me an email?